# Stop Java service gracefully, executed using nohoup command

Tags: java, spring-boot, nohup

I am a beginner in java spring-boot

when I start the java server through

`nohup java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

command my threads start their operations

After sometimes when I stop my server using

`kill -9 processid`

So my running thread data are lost.

I want to maintain a thread flag in the database whenever server stops.

I have tried to achieve the above scenario in following this tutorial [Spring Boot Shutdown](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown). It works properly but it breaks my security as anyone can use this API to stop my server.

I need a way to terminate my server gracefully and call `ContextClosedEvent` class.

Comment: Al the above is somewhat hazy, but a. as a general principle, you should be making sure your threads are prepared for being shut down and b. don't use `-9` if you want things closing down cleanly

Comment: Try to use gracefully shutdown properties availlable since Spring Boot `2.3.0` -> 

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-web-server-shutdown

Comment: The proper signal to terminate a Java JVM is signal 15, TERM. Not signal 9, KILL.

Comment: Frankly speaking you should not rely on a fact that your java program will always be gracefully shut down. You cannot control power outages.

Comment: @Harsh is your question resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No graceful shutdown support provided by Spring Boot is going to work if you use `kill -9`. That is `SIGKILL`, which can't be caught, blocked, or ignored, so of course your application can't do anything in response to it.

Use `kill -SIGTERM` to allow shutdown hooks to execute in your Java runtime.

Avoid magic numbers like 15 and 9; use meaningful symbols like `SIGTERM` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot version from 2.3 and later, special configuration for [graceful shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.graceful-shutdown) should be added to `application.yml`:

```
server:
  shutdown: graceful
```

From java doc:

> The WebServer should support graceful shutdown, allowing active requests time to complete

Another option is `immediate`:

> The WebServer should shut down immediately

Additional resource [Shutdown Spring Boot Applications Gracefully](https://www.amitph.com/spring-boot-graceful-shutdown/#Without_Graceful_Shutdown_Enabled)